Custom sorting of reviews in Elementor
I am trying to set up custom filtering of the reviews widget in Elementor. Basically what 'd like to do is add a new ACF field for product model, and then have my loop carousel template populate with the relevant reviews (e.g. reviews with that product tag) on pages dynamically. How would I go about doing this?
I've added a new field but can't figure out how to get around manually adding/inserting all of these reviews depending on the page.
here's the code i've tried so dar:
add_action('elementor/query/custom_review_filter', function($query) {
    if (is_page() && get_field('product_model')) {
        $product_model = get_field('product_model');
        $query->set('meta_key', 'product_model');
        $query->set('meta_value', $product_model);
    }
});


Try this, I modify the sorting query function:
add_action('elementor/query/my_custom_review_filter', function($query) {
    if (is_page() && get_field('product_model')) {
        $product_model = get_field('product_model');
        $query->set('post_type', 'review');
        $meta_query = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'product_model',
                'value' => $product_model,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
        );
        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
    }
});

